# double percent spark sql in jupyter notebook

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, jupyter-notebook, amazon-emr

I'm using a Jupyter Notebook on a Spark EMR cluster, want to learn more about a certain command but I don't know what the right technology stack is to search. Is that Spark? Python? Jupyter special syntax? Pyspark?

When I try to google it, I get only a couple results and none of them actually include the content I quoted. It's like it ignores the %%.

What does "%%spark_sql" do, what does it originate from, and what are arguments you can pass to it like -s and -n?

An example might look like

```
%%spark_sql -s true
select 
*
from df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are called [magic commands/functions](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jupyter/ipython_magic_commands.htm). Try running `%pinfo %%spark_sql` or `%pinfo2 %%spark_sql`in a Jupyter cell and see if it gives you a detailed information about `%%spark_sql`.